# Authentication using Facebook with Passportjs: what is accessToken for, what should I store after registration?

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, oauth, passport.js

I am using Passport to register/authenticate using Facebook.
When oAuth is successful, I am returned:

- `accessToken`
- `refreshToken`
- `profile`

Now... when a user successfully registers using Facebook, I store `accessToken` and the `profile` info.
When somebody wants to login, and goes through the oauth motions again, my app once more gets `accessToken` and `profile`.
Trouble is, `accessToken` is different. I actually expected the accessToken to be the same after the first authentication...

At this point, I am connecting my own local user with the facebook's `id` field from the profile. But... how would I actually use accessToken? Does it even make sense to keep it? If so, why would I actually keep it?

I actually expect accessToken to be the same, and use that to match a successful login. I obviously can't do that... so I am confused!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should store facebook Id. It should be in the `profile` object. Access token will change according to facebooks policy of authorization. What you should be doing is

1. Get the user to login through facebook
2. Check their facebook id against the facebook id in  your database.

Access tokens expire frequently as described [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending)

Answer (score 11):

You need to keep accessToken if you want to query facebook's API on behalf of your logged-in-via-facebook user. If you want to use facebook just for login only, you can discard it. If you want to ask facebook for the user's most recent status update, for example, you need to include that accessToken as a parameter when making that API call. The point of the accessToken is that it allows a set of operations on behalf of a user, but it expires so if it falls into the wrong hands it cannot be used to cause as much damage as a permanent token or the user's actual password. It will be different every time by design.

Comment: Yeah! A big light just came on after 2h of searching and reading :)